# Can I use this tool to migrate from OnPrem to Cloud?

Tags: azure-devops

Can I use this tool for migrating workitems from OnPrem to Cloud version of Azure DevOps?

Comment: Can you use *what* tool to migrate work items!?

Comment: Dose my answer help you to solve your issue/confuse, If yes, you could Accept it as an Answer , so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks

Comment: How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question, If yes, you could accept it as an answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks. If not, please let us know if you would like further assistance

Answer (score 1):

We can use the data migration tool for Azure DevOps. This tool provide the high fidelity way to migrate collection databases from Azure DevOps Server to Azure DevOps Services.
This means you can also use this tool to migrate your workItem from Server to Cloud.
You can refer the guidance doc: [Migrate data from Azure DevOps Server to Azure DevOps Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/migrate/migration-overview?view=azure-devops)
And here you can download the tool:https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54274